# Draw using textured QBrush without translating texture

Tags: c++, qt

I have made a simple texture of an outlined box and have the following snippet of code which draws a checkerboard pattern:

```
scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
ui->g_view->setScene(&scene);

QPixmap texture("block.png");
QBrush brush(texture);

int count = 0;
for(int x=0; x<1000; x += 50) {
    for(int y=0; y<1000; y += 50) {
        if (count % 2 == 0) {
            scene.addRect(x, y, 50, 50, Qt::NoPen, brush);
        }
        count++;
    }
    // Offset rows by 1
    count++;
}
```

This works fine:

[image]

However, when I modify the code so that the boxes are drawn "off grid":

```
scene.addRect(x + 5, y + 5, 50, 50, Qt::NoPen, brush);
```

The following output is produced:

[image]

What I expected to happen was that each call to addRect would draw the texture starting from the top corner each time.

However, for some reason qt translates the texture using the location that it is being drawn too, almost like the texture is infinitely tiled in the background and addRect is just cutting away a window.

How can I make drawRect behave as I expected, i.e. no matter what the values of x and y are the texture is always drawn from the top left corner.

Edit: block.png

[image]

Comment: share the block.png

Comment: @eyllanesc Added to the question

Comment: Providing a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would make life much simpler for answerers. I'd just play around with the code (that includes compile and run) and see if I find something. However, I don't bother crafting the `main`-method, setting up a `QGraphicsView` and stuff. Should be doable with less than 10 loc, but I think that's the responsibility of the asker.

Comment: @pasbi I'm not at the computer with this code on at the moment. I can provide a MWE in ~5 hours time. I don't think there is much more to it than what I have posted though, all I did was create a new project and then use the visual GUI editor to add a big graphicsview to the window named "g_view". The rest of the project is the code that I have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by instead using the `addPixmap` method.

```
//scene.addRect(x + 5, y + 5, 50, 50, Qt::NoPen, brush);
QGraphicsPixmapItem *pix_map = scene.addPixmap(texture);
pix_map->setPos(x + 5, y + 5);
```